# reading BIOS environmental variables with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, bios

I'm looking to get the BIOS environmental variables and not the OS ones. Does someone know how to do it in VBScript?

Comment: All environmental variables are provided by the OS since it provides the environment.

Comment: you mean bios settings ? which bios from which mark of computer ? publish what you'v tried

Answer (score 0):

Use WMI, and query the Win32_BIOS class.